# Cygwin git push hangs, msysgit okay

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

I'm behind a proxy, and I'm quite new to git and I'm on Windows XP.

I've been able to make a `git push origin master` work from msysgit but can't make it work in Cygwin with Cygwin's git.

I configured git using the following command lines in both environments:

```
git config --global user.name ...
git config --global user.email ...
git config --global http.proxy ...
```

I'm playing with a test Github repo. The issue I have is with the following command line:

```
git push origin master
```

In msysgit, I have the following result:

```
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 222 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://github.com/ymartineau/test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

which is okay, and in Cygwin, git asks username, but never asks user password and hangs.

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'http://github.com': ymartineau
```

I'll use msysgit bash for the moment, but I thought it could be interesting to benefit from Cygwin integration.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem on cygwin too. But after reading [the issue log](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/85), referenced by Paul, I fixed it by executing the following command:

```
git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass" #Note the lack of the file path.
```

Upon issuing a `git push` two dialogboxes appear after another. username and then password. It's not the best but at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug about this: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/85

The bug description also contains a workaround:

```
$ git config --global core.askpass /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

This will make prompt appear in a popup window

Comment: The link for the bug is dead. Any other way to get there?

Comment: @Sekkou527 The link has just been fixed