# Why can't I push to GitHub using cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

I am trying to run the following command:

```
git push github master
```

When I run this command in a mintty terminal the command prompt just hangs until i kill the process tree. There is no console output whatsoever.

```
bash.exe
  bash.exe
    git.exe
      git.exe
        git-remote-https.exe
```

Running the exact same command in a `cmd` window successfully pushes the master branch.

The remote configured is over HTTPS.

My question is, why does this command work in a basic command prompt but not with cygwin?

Is it an issue to do with how paths are interpreted?

I have seen a question asked [similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296740/cygwin-git-push-hangs-msysgit-ok), but their prompt gets to requesting the username, mine however does not.

Comment: Check if your `HOME` directory differs: what `%HOME%` is set to in Windows? What `$HOME` is set to in cygwin?

Comment: :) they are indeed different. Can I configure git to not require the HOME environment variable?

Comment: No, you need to set the same environment variable, HOME included. The easiest is to run your Apache with your local account.

Comment: This will break other tools within Cygwin though I'm guessing.

Comment: No, it won't. It will benefit from your environment.

Comment: Wait, so is the only option to do this to use the msysgit provided bash window? I love my cygwin :( I don't use my ssh keys to commit to github, just password. Could swear this worked perfectly yesterday, but now it decided to hang.

Comment: @Brad did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Cygwin gets confused between system Git and Cygwin Git.

The way I rectified this was to uninstall all versions of Git then reinstall the version of Git you want to use.

Either that or use a Mac. :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your cygwin ssh's public key to your github account?

https://github.com/settings/ssh

Edit: you have to be logged in to github for the above link

Comment: Added clarification that you need to be logged in to github to be able to see the link